# Centering navigation and title with Content body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm having a tuff time centering the navigation of my website with the content body. I'd like the navigation to center with that instead of the browser because it looks like its a bit left of the content body and doesn't quite look right.

Is that possible. http://www.bryananthonylewis.com/ Just a simple blog with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Would you agree that the "home" icon is what is causing it to be off center?  As in, it is off center by that amount?

Comment: I thought that as well but it seems like a lot more space than just the icon. Just kind of bugs me endlessly.

Comment: Remove the icon and see what happens. We can go from there.

Comment: Would you like the navigation and the content to be at the center of the browser or keep the content body at it's current position and align the navigation to it? Right now, the navigation is at the center of the browser window and the content body is slightly off.

Comment: Instead of defining a specific margin, why don't you just apply `text-align: center;` or something to your `#container`. And then you can reapply `text-align: left;` to your modals. That way they're always centered to the container.

Comment: I'd be up for centering everything @pentzzsolt I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: In that case, your question has been answered below by @Bodybag .

Comment: @Raphael Rafatpanah no it is not. It is the container of the content area, that div tag is not positioned to the center of the browser window.

Comment: @pentzzsolt, I did a screenshot and measured in photoshop after he removed the icon.  It was the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the wrong track here..

a quick scan using chromeinspect shows me you use span8 offset 2 for your main content (the first element within your container element right beneath #modal-contact), and i think you're main content is a bit to the right and not the header to the left.

my quick fix:

remove the offset,
and get a css style on that content with:

```
float: none;
margin: 0 auto; /*replace 0 for top margin*/
```

putting a width to the container as Pankaj suggests might work too, although you might loose dynamic width changes provided by bootstrap this way... didnt check so i might be wrong on that part

**update**

**another update to clarify**

remove previous fix.
in the container element right beneath your #modal-contact add a wrapping div,
not at the top of your page like i think you did...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="span8 offset2">
             blogcontent here
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**woops code tags were missing here**

i get a feeling this should do the same thing.
and i also believe that the header needs the same fix. but i'm not 100% sure, so pls try and comment if it works or not. this update is based on the official docs

[bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

**if things don't work, forget about my suggestion and stick to what works**

Comment: Let me try this real quick.

Comment: This worked. But now I'm having problems when its in tablet mode... screenshot... http://imgur.com/uyuLCSO

Comment: is the content positioned as you want? or is the header positioned as you want?

Comment: In desktop mode yes. for some reason it is left of the content in tablet width. I like where the content is in tablet mode and would like the nav to be in the same position if at all possible.

Comment: hm, i get the feeling we missed something here.. :-) the point of using the bootstrap is that it should align..can you try the updated answer that'll be visible in a sec

Comment: float: none; margin: 0 auto; to the .top-nav div and it worked perfectly! Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: be sure to try the update, as my quick fix was more or less raping the purpose of the bootstrap.

Comment: I added a class="wrapper" around everything and put a float: none; margin: 0 auto; on it and its not centering like we'd hoped.

Comment: yea i updated my post, but i forgot to wrap a part into code tags, so the div i wanted to suggest didnt show up.. reread pls

Comment: I change the "wrapper" class to "row" and removed my css and still have the same results.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I had to keep float: none; margin: 0 auto; on .container .span8.top-nav still. Other than that everything else worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your header. Actually your content below is not centered and this is happening because of unwanted div with classes "span8 offset2 middle" right under `div.container`. Fix this by removing that div altogether and overriding `.container` in your css file by

```
.container {
  width:777px;
}
```

an example of same edits inside web inspector of chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You will see that everything is lining up perfectly except, the icon does not have a width that is calculated in the centering.  You obviously want the icon TO have width.

So how can we do that?

Perhaps add something to the i tags like so:

```
i {

  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top; 

}
```

UPDATE:

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot above points to the problem.  After a media query, the site goes into tablet mode and the navigation is off.  Now, back to work!

Comment: In desktop mode yes. for some reason it is left of the content in tablet width. I like where the content is in tablet mode and would like the nav to be in the same position if at all possible. Besides that everything is lined up.